# Find a non-negative function $f$ such that $f \in \Omega(n^2)$ and $f \in o(n^2 \sqrt{n})$

Tags: limits, asymptotics, definition

A task from an old exam about Big O notation:

> Find a non-negative function f such that $f \in \Omega(n^2)$ and $f
> \in o(n^2 \sqrt{n})$

I'm not sure if I did it correctly, so I've checked both definitions on the internet and found that

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{f(n)}{g(n)} > 0 \Rightarrow f \in \Omega(g) $$

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{f(n)}{g(n)} = 0 \Rightarrow f \in o(g)$$

So we need to find a function $f$ which satisfies the following condition:

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{f(n)}{n^2} > 0 \text{ and }  \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{f(n)}{n^2\sqrt{n}} = 0 $$

If we choose $f(n) = 2n^2$, the first condition will be satisfied because $\frac{2n^2}{n^2} = 2 > 0$

The second condition should be satisfied too since $\frac{2n^2}{n^2\sqrt{n}} = \frac{2}{\sqrt{n}}$ and let $n$ go towards $\infty$, we end up with zero.

I hope it is correct like that?

Comment: It is indeed correct. $f(n) = n^2$ would have worked too, as well as $f(n) = cn^2$ for an arbitrary constant $c > 0$.